# How create resize panel with content in twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Some question about css.
I use boostrap for small web application. I need create some panels with menu and content.

Panel with content must resize with browser window, and there is a scroll must be in this, like in example:
http://www.bootply.com/L3tYJF0kU1#
But in this you can see - content not fits in panel.

It work correct if I set height of content container, like this:
http://www.bootply.com/1P4QfLZEen
But it not resize.

How I can do resize panel with scroll content&

Comment: Please edit your question to include all relevant code. Questions that **only** include links to code editors can be considered low-quality, so please include both the source code and links to the editor as an example.

Comment: Also I dont see anything wrong with the example you provided. All your content seems to fit in the panels.